# Apache + NodeJS + SocketIO + Secure Connection HTTPS

Tags: socket.io

I want to create a realtime app using NodeJS + SocketIO 1.0.
On the other hand, I want my app is able to listen on secure connection (HTTPS) and also insecure connection (HTTP). My existing webserver is apache.
For development purpose, I use self-assigned certificate.

But when I do that, browser is refusing to listen on secure connection (HTTPS)
https://mysite.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1414395697087-0 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

On insecure connection (HTTP) is working flawlessly.

What do I do wrong?
Please help!

Comment: I used [this](http://greengeckodesign.com/blog/2013/06/15/creating-an-ssl-certificate-for-node-dot-js/) tutorial and it worked in the end. Make sure your certificate is "trusted" within your OS/browser. I had to experiment a bit with all this.

Comment: @DerM Link down...